# How can i move variable outside the function?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
function type_of_value (){
 $(".typ_wartosci").each(function Type(){
  a = $(this).find(':selected').text();
})
}
alert(new type_of_value().a);
```

I want to display "a" variable, but I don't know how. 
I trying set variable before function, and use ".push" method, but doesn't work. I don't have an idea, what I should do next.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the method.  Also `a` is a global variable in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply return `a` like this -

```
function type_of_value (){
 let a = []
  $(".typ_wartosci").each(function(){
    var _this = $(this)
    if(_this.find(':selected')) {
      a.push(_this.find(':selected').text())
    }
  })
  return a
}
alert(new type_of_value())
```

If you are sure you have a single selected value, then -

```
function type_of_value (){
 let a
  $(".typ_wartosci").each(function(){
    var _this = $(this)
    if(_this.find(':selected').text()) {
      a = _this.find(':selected').text()
    }
  })
  return a
}
alert(new type_of_value())
```

Comment: Alert display only ",,,,"

Comment: @MichalRobak sorry declared `_this = $(this)` at wrong position...check now

Comment: Also can u please provide the HTML snippet you are parsing if you still getting an error

Comment: Thank you, ok and now i have result "%,,,," where "%" is ok ;) In all of them script the select list if from while loop, and now is 7 the same element, with the same class. What should i do to have one element e.x "%" not "%,,,". Make sense?

Comment: @MichalRobak simply make if statement to - `if(_this.find(':selected').text()) {` and let me know the output. Also if its a single item then you can also remove the array and store it in a variable only

Comment: And now alert return "[object Object]"

Comment: @MichalRobak Can you please check `_this.find(':selected').text()` by `console.log(_this.find(':selected').text())` I thinks its giving u an object so that's why you are gettting [object Object]

Comment: Sorry for a delay. In console log display correct char. Only behind function display object object

Comment: Ok everythings work ! ;) finally i use: `var wynik = new type_of_value();
    alert(type_of_value(wynik));` and alety display what i want :)